# How to bind nested object to form in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

Say I have a record like :

```
var project={
    manager:{
        id:1,
        name:"John"
    },
    name:"create ...",
    workers:[
        {name:'x',social_id:'xxx',age:11},
        {name:'x',social_id:'xxx',age:12}
    ]
};
```

And I want to edit this objec in a from like this:

[image]

I know I can bind the data to the form by `props`, however I wonder how to gather the updated data and send them to server?

BTW, the server accept `application/json` content-type when create or update the object.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer:

- Store all project info (including nested worker info) in state in a top-`<Project>` component.
- Define an `handleChange(worker)` handler in your `<Project>` component, that takes a worker record as parameter, and updates state accordingly.
- Define a `<Worker>` component, that takes as props a) worker-info from project-state, and b) the `this.handleChange` method as defined in `<Project>`
- In the worker component, add a handler on changes of each input item
- Whenever an input item in a worker changes, call `this.props. handleChange(worker)` on the parent `<Project>` component.